# Read json with rapidjson pointer

Tags: c++, json, qt, rapidjson

Trying to integrate `rapidjson` into my app. Used to read a (validated with an online tool) simple config file like:

```
{
    "filecontent": "appsettings",
    "fileversion": 1,
    "appsettings": {
        "general": {
            "sync": "false",
            "sound": "true"
        },
...
```

This is my code:

```
QString path = keypath( key ); //.prepend("/");
rapidjson::Value* hello = rapidjson::Pointer( "/appsettings/general/sound" ) //path.toStdString().c_str()
                          .Get(rapidJsonDoc_);

if ( hello ) {
    QVariant retStr( hello->GetString() );
    qDebug()<<"--> " <<path<<" --> " << retStr;
    ret = QVariant::fromValue( retStr );
}else{
    qDebug()<<"Value not found!";
}
return ret;
```

If I prepend the pointer string with `/`, as I understand the examples, it says `value not found`.
If I remove the slash, `if (hello)` is true, but does not return an expected value.

`rapidJsonDoc_` is of type `rapidjson::Document`.

Please help me with the correct syntax. I am looking at the source code of rapidjson and can't understand a thing, it is so full of templates and complex signatures...

update:

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034336/how-to-change-qjsonobject-value-in-a-qjson-hierarchy-without-using-copies#) post modifying a Qt QJsonDocument is not possible like I want.

Comment: Since you're already using Qt, why not just use [its built-in Json support](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html)?

Comment: Because I could not figure out how to write a document by just passing a string path like above (aka pointer) and a value. For reading I implemented the pointer myself, before finding out that rapidjson has the pointer stuff buildin.