# How to recursive create QJsonObject's without copies

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, qjson

Might relate to [How to change QJsonObject value in a QJson hierarchy without using copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034336/how-to-change-qjsonobject-value-in-a-qjson-hierarchy-without-using-copies/29361151), but the answer is basically, it doesn't work, maybe things have changed since then.
Given is the following signature:

```
void addToJson(const QStringList& path, QJsonObject& target, const QJsonObject& object)
```

It should build a JSON object based on the `path` and add `object`, e.g:

```
  path: obj,obj2,obj3
  ->
      "obj": {
        "obj2": {
          "obj3": {
          }
        }
      }
```

`object` would be added to obj3.

Current implementation is:

```
void addToJson(const QStringList& path, QJsonObject& target, const QJsonObject& object)
{
    if(path.isEmpty())
    {
        target = object;
        return;
    }

    QString objName = path.first();

    QJsonObject tmpObj = target[objName].toObject();
    addToJson(path.mid(1), tmpObj, object);
    target[objName] = tmpObj;
}
```

Can it be written, to avoid the copies (basically you would have a lot of deep copies in each iteration)?

The `[]` operator gives you a `QJsonValueRef`, what is good, but if you want to add something to it, you would need to convert it to a `QJsonObject` again and not a `QJsonValueRef`, which breaks everything.